# Studder first starting

Tags: engine, ignition, hyundai, ignition-coil, tucson

Hyundai Tucson 2008. Gasoline model.

I live in a very hot climate and when I  start my car in the morning it studders for a while. If I pump the gas, it disappears and doesn't come back. I experience this pretty much every morning. What could be the cause ?

Comment: When you say pump the gas, do you mean Rev the engine high of just give quick jabs on the throttle that don't give the engine time to respond?

Comment: I mean, while the car in park position, I hit the gas pedal. The rpm goes to 4-5k just for a few seconds and studder stops.

Comment: Does the shuddering happen with the engine cold or hot?

Comment: I live in the tropic island. There is no cold weather. So it is 30 degrees or so.

Comment: HandyHowie is asking if this happens when the engine itself is completely warm (100+C)? I know it doesn't get that warm where you live ;-)

Comment: @Paulster2 in that case no. This only happens in the morning when engine is resting for 8-12 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you need to clean your intake tract, mass air flow sensor, and throttle body, plus change the air filter if you haven't done so recently. I would bet you have some carbon or gunk causing the engine to hesitate in some situations. The idle air control valve may be dirty/sticky causing the issue as well.

Do a complete upper end cleaning and I will bet this issue will be a thing of the past.